# Translation in JavaScript like gettext in PHP?

Tags: javascript, gettext, translate

I am using `gettext` in my PHP code, but I have a big problem. All my JavaScript files are not affected by the translation, can somebody tell me an easy way to get the translations in the chosen language into JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way is having a PHP file write the translations from `gettext` into JavaScript variables.

js_lang.php:

```
word_hello = "<?php echo gettext("hello"); ?>"
word_world = "<?php echo gettext("world"); ?>"
word_how_are_you = "<?php echo gettext("how_are_you"); ?>"
```

and then include it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_lang.php"></script>
```

I would also recommend this method in conjunction with the translation plugins S.Mark mentions (which are very interesting!).

You can define the dictionary in the current page's header, too, without including an external file, but that way, you would have to look up and send the data on every page load - quite unnecessary, as a dictionary tends to change very rarely.

Comment: Pekka, how should you manage this for a very large website with many translations? would the generated language file be too large? (Let's say Facebook size just for fun) Or should we just stick to generating the HTML and text server side and use our current PHP language framework? Thanks

Comment: @Kenny Re the "very large" aspect, unless you're talking about megabytes of data needed for one translation, I think having one external JavaScript translation file per language - be it manually set up, cached, or generated by PHP - should work fine. It'll be loaded only once (make sure caching is configured correctly) and will provide all necessary words for all contexts of the site.

Comment: This does not take into consideration many of the problems that face real translations. The easiest example would be pluralization changes based on the data. So without any internationalization in your javascript code, you are unable to react to such differences.

Comment: @AlexSexton fair point. Is there a JS localization library that can deal with multiple plurals and such?

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be many great options. If you're using Dojo, they have great i18n support. There seems to be one decent `gettext` compatible implementation in JavaScript, which would handle these situations: http://jsgettext.berlios.de/ - I haven't used it in the real-word ever, so I can't quite recommend it yet. A good start, regardless.

Answer (score 16):

I generally export the translations in a JavaScript structure:

```
var app = {};
var app.translations = {
  en: {
    hello: "Hello, World!",
    bye: "Goodbye!"
  },
  nl: {
    hello: "Hallo, Wereld!",
    bye: "Tot ziens!"
  }
};
```

The current language of the page texts can be defined using: `<html xml:lang="en" lang="nl">`

This can be read in JavaScript:

```
var currentLanguage = document.documentElement.lang || "en";
app.lang = app.translations[ currentLanguage ] || app.translations.en;
```

And then you can write code like this:

```
alert( app.lang.hello );
```

---

Optionally, a `i18n()` or `gettext()` function can bring some intelligence, to return the default text if the key does not exist). For example:

```
function gettext( key )
{
  return app.lang[ key ] || app.translations.en[ key ] || "{translation key not found: " + key + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try, [jQuery i18n](http://recurser.com/articles/2008/02/21/jquery-i18n-translation-plugin/) or [jQuery localisation](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html)

An example for jQuery i18n, and of course you need to generate JSON based dictionary from language file from php

```
var my_dictionary = { 
    "some text"  : "a translation",
    "some more text"  : "another translation"
}
$.i18n.setDictionary(my_dictionary);


$('div#example').text($.i18n._('some text'));
```

Comment: i have nevere tryt that, and its comming in combinasion whit json, alerts and more.

Comment: or you might try http://i18next.com comes with additional gettext to json converter. and is full featured.

Answer (score 4):

[JSGettext](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/jsgettext/) ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110825094522/http://developer.berlios.de/projects/jsgettext/)) is best implementation of GNU gettext spec. 
First download JSGETTEXT package and include in your page
/js/Gettext.js

```
<?php
$locale = "ja_JP.utf8";
if(isSet($_GET["locale"]))$locale = $_GET["locale"];
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="gettext" type="application/x-po" href="/locale/<?php echo $locale ?>/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Gettext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Test!
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code for example

```
window.onload = function init(){
var gt = new Gettext({ 'domain' : 'messages' });
alert(gt.gettext('Hello world'));
}
```

For reference find below link. It's working fine without converting .js file to .php.

[Click here](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/05/29/dynamic-javascript-localization-with-gettext-and-php/)

Comment: http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jsgettext and 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsgettext.berlios/

Answer (score 2):

You can make your life much easier if you get rid of bad habit to use string literals in your code. That is, instead of

```
 alert("Some message")
```

use

```
alert($("#some_message_id").text())
```

where "#some_message_id" is a hidden div or span generated on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

As a further hint there's a perl script called po2json which will generate json from a .po file.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript implementation of GNU gettext API these links can be also useful:
    http://tnga.github.io/lib.ijs
    http://tnga.github.io/lib.ijs/docs/iJS.Gettext.html

```
//set the locale in which the messages will be translated
iJS.i18n.setlocale("fr_FR.utf8") ;
//add domain where to find messages data. can also be in .json or .mo
iJS.i18n.bindtextdomain("domain_po", "./path_to_locale", "po") ;
//Always do this after a `setlocale` or a `bindtextdomain` call.
iJS.i18n.try_load_lang() ; //will load and parse messages data from the setting catalog.
//now print your messages
alert( iJS.i18n.gettext("messages to be translated") ) ;
//or use the common way to print your messages
alert( iJS._("another way to get translated messages") ) ;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers will not be of any use if the external linked page changes in future

Answer (score 1):

This library seems the best implementation of getText in javascript:

http://messageformat.github.io/Jed/

https://github.com/messageformat/Jed

example from the documentation:

```
<script src="jed.js"></script>
<script>
var i18n = new Jed({
  // Generally output by a .po file conversion
  locale_data : {
    "messages" : {
      "" : {
        "domain" : "messages",
        "lang"   : "en",
        "plural_forms" : "nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);"
      },
      "some key" : [ "some value"]
    }
  },
  "domain" : "messages"
});

alert( i18n.gettext( "some key" ) ); // alerts "some value"
</script>
```