# Gettext in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I follow this solution :

[Translation in JavaScript like gettext in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400106/translation-in-javascript-like-gettext-in-php)

js-lang.php :

```
lang_error_empty_field = "<?php echo _("Lütfen boş alan bırakmayın"); ?>";
```

signin.php :

```
<script src="assets/layout/scripts/js-lang.php" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!-- LAYOUT SCRIPTS END -->

<!-- PAGE SCRIPTS START -->
<script src="assets/pages/scripts/signin.js"></script>
<!-- PAGE SCRIPTS END -->
```

signin.js :

```
if (!email || !password) {
    showError(lang_error_empty_field);
    hideError(3000);
    return;
}
```

The error is :

> GET http://localhost:8835/assets/layout/scripts/js-lang.php
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Normally gettext works, but i can not use in javascript files.
How can i use gettext in javascript ?

**UPDATE**

error.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include("js-lang.php");
?>
```

Still same error in here. I can not handle any error.

Comment: Is `js-lang.php` throwing any errors?  Turn on error reporting, check the PHP logs, and check the response in the browser's debugging tools.  The error implies that there's nothing being returned.

Comment: @David how do i open error reporting ?

Comment: First Google result for "php error reporting": http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php